# How do I prevent netcore exe leaking local details about developer / build environment?

Tags: .net-core

I have a console application in net core 5 that is being published to a single file, self-contained exe via the publish command. The app links and runs as expected, however if you open the exe in a text editor, you can see details about the environment where the app was built.

`dotnet publish --configuration Release -r win-x86 --self-contained true -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract=true -p:PublishTrimmed=true  -p:DebugType=None -p:DebugSymbols=false`

The above results in a single exe, but despite specifying no debugging, if you search the exe file, you will find the original path to the .pdb file embedded inside of it. In this case, the path contains the developer's name, and this is not acceptable.

Is there a way to ensure all local path information is excluded? Either by the pdb being linked via a relative path instead of absolute, or being suppressed entirely?

Comment: Not an answer but wondering if you couldn’t create a symlink and build/pub against that to at least obfuscate the path?